# Get Width with Javascript

Tags: javascript, width

I'm pretty rookie here, so be gentle. I've poked around here and other places on the internet and can't figure this out.

1. I'm trying to determine the width of a div.
2. I'd like that to be in percentage.
3. I do NOT want to use JQuery (trying to learn Javascript as much as
   possible)
4. I'm failing miserably. Why won't "theWidth" (below) yield anything?

Any help appreciated. Thanks, dp

HTML

```js
theWidth = document.getElementById("titleBG").style.width;
document.getElementById("titleBG").innerHTML = "Width = " + theWidth;
```

```css
#titleBG{
  width:50%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#ffcc33;
}
```

```html
<div id="titleBG">
</div>
```

Comment: Width that's set by CSS rules is not available from the element's "style" object. Instead, you'll have to use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: Instead of `getComputedStyle` you can use `getBoundingClientRect().width`

Comment: did you try anything from below? they both work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use element.offsetWidth here

Getting a percentage is going to be irrelevant - its always going to be 50% of the current viewport you are in.

That might not be the case if you have a wrapping div or some other elements on the page that may limit the width of the div, but with your current code that's the case.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth

```js
theWidth = document.getElementById("titleBG").offsetWidth;
document.getElementById("titleBG").innerHTML = "Width = " + theWidth;
```

```css
#titleBG{
  width:50%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#ffcc33;
}
```

```html
<div id="titleBG">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The most accurate way to get an element size (and even position) is to use

```
Element.getBoundingClientRect()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
or

```
window.getComputedStyle(element[, pseudoElt])
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

or

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth (similar to getBoundingClientRect, it just returns an integer)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth (gets the total scrollable width area (i.e: when element has overflow))

You can than calculate the percentage by getting the same way that element's parent (GBCR)width and calculating the `%` using `Number( (100/(parentWidth/width)).toFixed(3) )`

```js
var title = document.getElementById("titleBG");
var width = title.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var pwidth = title.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().width;

title.innerHTML = "Computed Width= "+ window.getComputedStyle(title, null).width +"<br>"+
  " GBCRWidth= " + width +"<br>"+
  " Perc= "+ Number((100/(pwidth/width)).toFixed(3)) +"%";
```

```css
#titleBG{
  width:50%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#ffcc33;
}
```

```html
<div id="titleBG"></div>
```